# Saga Catchment Area not giving expected (useful) output

Tags: saga, catchment-area

I am identifying a catchment network from a DEM in QGIS3 (v3.0.3) (on a mac  v10.13.4), however the step to identify the Catchment Area is not working.

I have an input DEM, with layer CRS set to UTM55S.  I am using Method 0 (Deterministic).  The output layer for the Catchment Area has no identifiable channel networks.

[image: Catchment Area]

I am using a hydrologically corrected DEM (provided by Geosciences Australia), clipped to the area of interest.  I have saved the output raster in geotiff format and am working from this (could this be the problem?).

I am using SAGA processing toolbox.

I first run Fill Sinks, which gives an expected output - I check the difference between the original and Filled DEM and nothing stands out.  I then run the Catchment Area using the default options and don't see what I expected.

Running the Channel Network algorithm is not giving me what I would expect - the network is entirely disconnected.  I tried a few different initiation thresholds (greater than option - 0.1 -> 1e-6). These are subbasins of major rivers, I would expect to see a dominant stream network.
[image: Higher initial threashold]

[image: Close up of a much lower threshold]

I have read a lot of different responses around this topic, but mostly they deal with wrong initiation thresholds (so blank output if too high), wrong projections (but UTM is suggested as appropriate), or CRS not being consistent (I have set CRS through Set Layer CRS to ensure this isn't the problem).

Comment: IMHO the catchment area by `Deterministic 8` is not much appealing,  since it limits possible flow directions. I like `Deterministic infinity` which probably gives you what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried Deterministic Infinity and had the same problem.

Comment: I see. What I read from the first image is that the Catchment Area is too small (~0.00212) and even threshold value as small as 0.1 does not easily pick them up as streams. But threshold value itself is not the main issue here. Rather, your DEM would require more help (eg `Flow Direction`) to keep the flow. Can you share the link to the data?

Comment: The DEM is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=16jMha2unaq8yolz_F_yNLkNGmgM0A5Ah. I tried threshold values as low as 1e-6 with no luck.

Comment: Got that, Thanks! Firstly, the file you have (GA claims it is on UTM55S), is on geographycal (Latlon) WGS74. So the pixel size being (0.000277773,-0.000277789) causes problem in your work. You need to fix it by (1) Assign projection to `EPSG:4322` then (2) Warp it to UTM55S (eg `EPSG:32755`).

Comment: Another (and more critical) issue is that you have a huge basin in the center of your study area, where preprocessing such as Fill Sinks will produce completely flat area. I honestly do not know how to deal with it. (Removing low area, say < 300m, may work. But it would not be your intention.)

Comment: Thanks - I picked that catchment as the first to work on at random.  I'll grab one that might be easier to start with and come back to this once I've the basics ironed out.  Doing the reprojections is fine thanks - found what I should have been doing.

Comment: @Esme_ I have had the same problem with trying to determine catchments zones for active drainages in a piedmont alluvial fan system. I can visually differentiate the relict channel systems and the active drainages, but all I can ever get the GIS tools to "see" are tiny, disconnected segments of stream flows, so I can't run any watershed or catchment delineation tools. Pulling my hair out! Did you ever find a solution to your problem, and if so, could you please post a successful workflow? Enormous thanks!

Comment: @L.Rouse I, unfortunately, found the solution by switching catchments to something without those complexities and fixing the issues with the reprojections.  In my case, this was a randomly chosen catchment to learn some techniques. Apologies I can't provide more detail, this was for a previous job and I haven't touched this in a couple of years now.  Good luck fixing your issues.